# How to detect Retina HD display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

`UIScreen` has a new, `nativeScale` property in iOS 8 but the documentation does not say a word about it.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat nativeScale
```

There is also a `scale` property but the docs say it is 2 for retina displays.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat scale
```

I am wondering if there is a way to distinguish the displays. The reason why I need to know whether the device has Retina HD display is because I want to request images with different sizes based on the displays.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: scale property will be used it shows the 3 for retina HD display

Comment: I am getting `2` but I am running iPhone 6 simulator. Does it show `3` when ran on the device?

Comment: iPhone 6 plus has ratina HD not 6

Comment: I have checked for the iPhone 6+ its giving me 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below works very well to detect type of display on iPhone6Plus.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 3.0)
    NSLog(@"Retina HD"); 
else
    NSLog(@"Non Retina HD");
```

Comment: Question is about retina HD

Comment: @Bhumit And this is the answer

Comment: Seems like its being edited after my comment. It is now correct

Comment: Call to `respondsToSelector` not needed (unless you want to support iOS 3.2 or *lower*)

Comment: I am totally getting 2 for this.... I am running in the debugger, does that matter??

Answer (score -1):

Check the below code:

```
 CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);

NSLog(@"WIDTH:%f",screenSize.height);
 NSLog(@"WIDTH:%f",screenSize.width);



float height =screenSize.height;
float width = screenSize.width;

NSString *deviceType=@"";

if (height==1136.000000 && width==640.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 5,5S and 5C Retina";
}
if (height==1920.000000 && width==1080.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 6 Plus Retina Downsample";
}

if (height==2208.000000 && width==1242.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 6 Plus Retina";
}

if (height==1334.000000 && width==750.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 6 Retina";
}
if (height==960.000000 && width==640.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 4 and 4S Retina";
}
if (height==480.000000 && width==320.000000)
{
    deviceType =@"iPhone 3g and 3gs Non retina ";
}

NSLog(@"Your Result:%@",deviceType);
```

Reference:

[iPhone Resoution](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/)

Comment: What are the bets that your code breaks on the iPhone 6S, and on the iPhone 7 at the latest?

Comment: Agreed, this is essentially guaranteed to break in the future. Checking the `scale` on `[UIScreen mainScreen]` is a much better approach.